# Can Source Insight Project View show the file tree? not just the file name list

Tags: source-insight

I have so many files in different folders of my project. I want to view and edit them in Source Insight, i found the project view only show the file name not the tree view as in Visual Studio. Is it possible to show the file tree in Source Insight?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ay6O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNV0a.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Project window open you can change the properties to be "directory view". It's not quite what you're after but does have the file tree at the top and the files at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Source Insight show the tree view but in slightly different way.

In project window press right click on project name and then select "Project File Browser".

It will show folder tree in upper half section and content of selected folder in lower half section.